# Frame does not Show Contents

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui

I am trying to use `<Frame></Frame>` syntax to set my Name contents inside of it but it does not shows the `Label` syntax and `Entry` syntax that I have created inside the frame.

The code:

```
<VerticalStackLayout Spacing="10" Margin="10,10,10,0">

    <Frame Padding="0" HeightRequest="60">
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="Name" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50"></Label>
            <Entry
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HeightRequest="10"
                WidthRequest="200">
            </Entry>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Frame>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

The output:

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYrms.png)

I just could not wrapped my head around it. I tried `Padding` and `HeightRequest` to check whether the frame was small enough to not show the contents, but that is not the case.

UPDATE:

To display content in a `Frame` Class is to replace `Frame` Class with `Border` Class.

```
<VerticalStackLayout Spacing="10" Margin="10,10,10,0">

    <Border Padding="0" HeightRequest="60">
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="Name" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="50"></Label>
            <Entry
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                HeightRequest="10"
                WidthRequest="200">
            </Entry>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Border>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

> The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead, and to set shadows using the Shadow bindable property on VisualElement. For more information, see Border and Shadow. - Jason (Xamarin MVP)

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame)

> The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use Border instead, and to set shadows using the Shadow bindable property on VisualElement. For more information, see Border and Shadow.

Comment: It works! Lovely. Thank you for the help. By using `Border` syntax instead of `Frame` it solves the problem.